# What does swapping OpenIDs do?

Tags: support

What does swapping OpenIDs do besides rearranging ID order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- OpenID deletion can only be done for Alternative OpenID. So if you want to delete the main one, you need to swap it with the alt OpenID first.
- When you copy profiles to other stackexchange sites only the primary OpenID is copied along with your other information.

Comment: this also affects which one gets overwritten when you add a new openid and you already have two.